# How to fix django two-factory authentication setup?

Tags: python, django

I have installed and configured this package https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth for my Django app, to Admin site.
Next step was to create a user and to setup this 2FA, but when i try to login for the first time, i'm always being redirected to
`/account/login/?next=/admin/`

and i can't setup two-factor authentication. 
Has anyone faced with this problem?

Comment: This is how I resolved the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243363/457935

The two_factor code's `has_permission` override calls the default admin `has_permission` and adds in a call to check if an OTP has been received which it wont' have in the admin login. So the change redirects to the two_factor setup flow if an OTP isn't yet present.